# Rails stopped logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

My rails app running in development environment stopped logging all of a sudden and I am not able to figure out why.

I tried logging into a new file by doing

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/temp.log')
config.log_level = :debug
```

But still no luck. The new file temp.log was created but nothing is logged in the file. The thing is this happens on my development server running nginx (I run my rails app using "rails s -d" on this server). The exact same files, when I run on my local machine (my own computer), logging works fine.

So I feel the reason logging is not working is because of something specific to the server, but then I didn't do anything much on the server (e.g. I didn't install new gems, etc.) Logging has been working fine until few days ago.

When I go to rails console

```
rails c
> Rails.logger.debug "hello"
=> true
```

I do get "hello" logged into 'log/temp.log' specified above in config file.

I think permission on log directory or file is ok. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a locking issue which you might be able to solve after removing the call to the logger which causes this.

I ran into this issue with Redmine 1.x,
I found newrelic_rpm entry in the production.log, saying it didn't run, and 1 line of a Redmine plugin init.

After removing both, newrelic_rpm from the environment.rb (config.gem line), and the plugin logger init message, the logging facility appears to be restored and log entries are appearing again.